# Trying to undersand linked lists in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

So I'm new to Java and trying to get an understanding for linked lists. I found a tutorial on YouTube which is describing the steps in making a linked list. This is where I am stuck:

```
public class List {

    public String bookName;
    public int millionsSold;

    public List next;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }

}
```

`public List next`

-what exactly is this and what does it mean? Is it some kind of container?

Comment: ohhhh dear. You need to read a super elementary description of Java classes.

Comment: It's simply a reference to another object of type `List`.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: [LinkedLists](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html)

Comment: @user2291971 Are you doing data structures class by any chance? ...And the rain of answers comes...

Comment: @Colleen probably data structures more than Java

Answer (score 2):

Its just a reference variable to hold reference of next element in `LinkedList`, you could use `LinkedList` implementation directly instead of writing one

Answer (score 2):

in a `Linked List` implementation `Next` typically refers to the next node (or link) in the sequence.

Use:

```
List head = new List();  
head.next = new List();
...   

void iterate()  
{   
     List node = head;
     while(node != null)
     {  
         System.out.println(node);  
         node=node.next;
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to implement is a [singly-linked-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list). That means each element of your list refers to the next element in the list, or to the end of the list:

[image: Illustration of singly-linked-list taken from the Wikipedia article]

In your case, `next` would be the reference to the next box, so basically the value stored in the big dots in the picture. The list itself would be the reference to the first element (i.e. the box containing the 12 in the picture).

Answer (score 2):

> Each element (we will call it a node) of a list is comprising of two items - the data and a reference to the next node. The last node has a reference to null. The entry point into a linked list is called the head of the list. It should be noted that head is not a separate node, but the reference to the first node. If the list is empty then the head is a null reference.

[image]

[*Linked Lists - Victor Adamchik - Carnegie Mellon University*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html)

Answer (score -1):

This statement declares a variable which points to another object with the same "List" type.

BTW, you don't need to create a linked list by yourself unless you want practicing your coding skills. There is a built-in class already: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: But clearly in this case that's not the `List` being referred to.

Comment: Yes, in this case, it reference the List class itself. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Nit-picky but List is the interface, LinkedList is probably what OP is looking for

Comment: @Bucco list is actually the name of OP's class